# Grub Customizer Theme Error - Can't Find "theme.txt"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, themes, burg

What I've Done:

- Fresh Install of Ubuntu 14.04
- Installed BURG on all 4 of my hard drives (plus hd0)
- Seems to work fine
- Install GRUB Customizer and run as root in BURG Mode

Then I get this error:

```
 *** initializing (w/o specified bootloader type)…
   * reading partition info…
   * Loading Framebuffer resolutions (background process)
   * Finding out if this is a live CD
sh: 1: hwinfo: not found
 *** initializing (w/ specified bootloader type)…
   * Checking if the config directory is clean
 *** loading configuration
 *** loading - preserveConfig: no
   * unsetting saved config
 *** loading settings
 *** loading grub list
   * loading scripts…
   * loading proxies…
   * cleaning up proxy configuration…
   * creating proxifiedScript links & chmodding other files…
   * running burg-mkconfig
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
   * restoring grub configuration
   * removing invalid proxies from list
   * loading completed
 *** grub list completely loaded
 *** loading saved grub list
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
     exception '28InvalidStringFormatException'
 with message 'theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes' given path: 'saved''
 in /build/buildd/grub-customizer-4.0.6/src/Model/ThemeManager.cpp:68
```

When I try switching to any theme it says it can't find "theme.txt".

ALL of my themes seem to contain /boot/burg/themes path though.

"/boot/burg/themes/sora/theme" exists. But why "theme" not "theme.txt"?

Renaming doesn't help.

Any solution is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to the simple theme method which provides some options like color, wallpaper and font you can install complex theme packages to get an even better looking boot menu.

There are several download sources like this thread at [http://ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1823915) (needs account)
or search for 'grub' at http://gnome-look.org

Just download such a package (which is in `tar.gz` format in most cases) and add it to the list of available themes by using the add button next to the theme chooser.

After changing the theme you'll see a simple editor which gives a preview of images and allows some file management. Modified theme contents will be saved when you're pressing the save button.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and i used this method...

> Fully remove burg:
>
> `sudo apt-get remove --purge burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common`
>
> Reinstall burg:
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes && sudo burg-install "(hd0)" && sudo update-burg && sudo burg-emu`

and...

> I am noob, but as soon as none of the solutions I found worked, I decided to share.
>
> I've experienced the same problem after I updated Ubuntu and somehow loader was changed from BURG back to GRUB. I tried to follow the tutorial and ended up with the same set of problems: "theme.txt not found", "theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes'", burg-emu started looking like this. When I purged and reinstalled both burg and grub-customizer once again, I tried to launch burg-emu via terminal right after running update-burg. Surprisingly, it worked, but the list was full of different Ubuntu versions. I launched Grub Customizer to get rid of them, and it broke my burg.cfg. I opened /etc/default/burg, changed GRUB_THEME to "saved" instead of non-existing "theme.txt" which Grub Customizer tried to find and updated burg.cfg, which solved the issue.

So after reinstall i typed:

```
update-burg && burg-emu
```

after that i can switch themes with f2
but dont try to run grub-customizer cos its mess all ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should be having a theme.txt file for all your themes. Most likely, the theme file that you renamed is not the actual theme file and therefore wouldn't work regardless of renaming. 
This is the tutorial I followed and it worked for me : http://develop.alpdesigns.ch/pages/ubuntu/brug-and-theme-configuration.html
I would revert back to grub, purge all installed burg packages and reinstall again. Maybe try the linked tutorial, as I said, it did work without issue for me...

Answer (score 0):

1. Fully remove burg:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge burg burg-common burg-emu burg-pc burg-themes burg-themes-common
   ```
2. Reinstall burg:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes && sudo burg-install "(hd0)" && sudo update-burg && sudo burg-emu
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am noob, but as soon as none of the solutions I found worked, I decided to share.

I've experienced the same problem after I updated Ubuntu and somehow loader was changed from BURG back to GRUB. I tried to follow [the tutorial](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-make-your-dual-boot-better-with-burg) and ended up with the same set of problems: "theme.txt not found", "theme index file path must contain '/boot/burg/themes'", `burg-emu` started looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdjBa.png). When I purged and reinstalled both `burg` and `grub-customizer` once again, I tried to launch `burg-emu` via terminal right after running  `update-burg`. Surprisingly, it worked, but the list was full of different Ubuntu versions. I launched Grub Customizer to get rid of them, and it broke my `burg.cfg`. I opened `/etc/default/burg`, changed `GRUB_THEME` to "saved" instead of non-existing "theme.txt" which Grub Customizer tried to find and updated `burg.cfg`, which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Grub Customizer. It just corrupts burg.cfg file. That's why it can't find theme.txt file
Instead, choose a theme from burg emulator directly. Just type "sudo burg-emu" in Terminal. But never use Grub Customizer to configure your burg.cfg file.

Answer (score 0):

Download theme.
Unzip it.
either install by run install.sh script in theme folder
or copy theme folder inside downloaded folder other than install.sh.

Look at here.
https://www.fosslicious.com/2019/12/easy-way-install-grub-themes-ubuntu-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to move all the files in the sub-directory and move it to the main. Remove install.sh and the other files.

1. Just cut these files

   [image]
2. It should look like this in the end.

   [image]